# ListView utilising customer adapter shifts edit text value from item removed to next item

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using a custom adapter for my ListView that inflates a layout for each list item. For each list item, there is a button in the layout that allows the user to remove the item from the list view. There is also an edit text for user input. I am running into issues that when a edit text is filled, but then the user removes that item, the value shifts to the edit text for the list item below it. For instance, if the edit text in position 1 of my list view has the value '25' in it, then the user clicks to remove the item, the value '25' shifts to the new item in position 1.

My adapter class

```
public class PartOrderAddPartAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Part> {
private static final int layoutResourceId = R.layout.part_information_list_item;
private List<Part> partList;
private final Context context;

public PartOrderAddPartAdapter(Context context, List<Part> partList) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, partList);
    this.context = context;
    this.partList = partList;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
    }

    Part p = getItem(position);

    TextView partNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.part_number);
    TextView partDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.part_description);
    EditText quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    Button removePartButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.remove_part_button);

    partNumber.setText(p.getPartNumber());
    partDescription.setText(p.getDescription());

    removePartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            partList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public Part getItem(int position) {
    return partList.get(position);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that the view for the row is reused.
It does not create a new one when an unused one exists. You receive it in convertView for re-fillling - as you can see in your own code.

So, if there was a previous value there then it will still be there.
It is up to you to clear it.

Simply put, you MUST set values for ALL the fields in the row. You can not assume anything about the value that is there.

Answer (score 0):

As you are reusing the views, any changes you make to a view will be visible when it is reused (i.e. when you scroll or refresh the list). In your case you are removing the item from the list but not clearing the text from the view. The view is then shifted up when you call notifyDataSetChanged() and the text is still visible.

**What you need to do is clear the text from the view in that position before calling notifyDataSetChanged().**

Another thing to watch out for is the use of conditional statements when reusing views in a list adapter. In short, always follow an if with an else to ensure your view is reset to a default state when the statement evaluates to false.